# missing ios 5 Headers giving theos errors

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cydia, tweak

So yeah heres the error code when compiling from my ipad via theos

```
  Making all for bundle iNotitweet...
  Compiling iNotitweetController.m...
  In file included from iNotitweetController.m:2:
  /var/theos/include/Twitter/Twitter.h:7:36: error: _ABAddressBookAddRecord.h: No
 such file or directory
 In file included from /var/theos/include/Twitter/Twitter.h:9,
             from iNotitweetController.m:2:
 /var/theos/include/Twitter/NSCoding-Protocol.h:8: warning: duplicate declaration for protocol 'NSCoding'
   In file included from iNotitweetController.m:2:
   /var/theos/include/Twitter/Twitter.h:13: error: cannot find interface declaration
   for '_ABAddressBookAddRecord', superclass of 'Twitter'
   iNotitweetController.m: In function '-[iNotitweetController composeTweet]':
   iNotitweetController.m:48: error: 'TWTweetComposeViewController' undeclared (first
   use in this function)
   iNotitweetController.m:48: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
   iNotitweetController.m:48: error: for each function it appears in.)
   iNotitweetController.m:48: error: 'twtComposer' undeclared (first use in this
   function)
   iNotitweetController.m:50: error: expected expression before '^' token
   make[2]: *** [obj/iNotitweetController.m.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [internal-bundle-all_] Error 2
   make: *** [iNotitweet.all.bundle.variables] Error 2
```

im using rpetrich's headers and stole the twitter header from from the freemanrepo on github, could anybody please tell me what these errors mean and where i can find _ABAddressBookAddRecord.h im following this code http://pastebin.com/rArx47Bx and this tutorial http://tumblr.leonnears.com/post/17966636490/create-ncwidget-ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those headers are compatibility headers for old versions of iPhoneOS (even before it was iOS), and I do not recommend the continued use of them - there is no real need to support versions below 4.3.3 anyways (or even 5.0.1), as almost everyone is on at least one of those two firmwares. For the most recent headers, either dump your own from the dyldcache (using kennytm's dyld_decache from [here](https://github.com/kennytm/Miscellaneous/downloads)), or you can find the SpringBoard headers for iOS 5 [here](https://github.com/autopear/SpringBoard-iOS5-Headers).

Comment: Also, if this answered your question, please mark it as such.